# DVDs not playing

Tags: 13.04, dvd

To put it simply, I'm trying to watch and rip DVDs on my computer, but it never works. I have VLC and libdvdcss, but the DVD just doesn't load and evidently, doesn't play. Could you guys help me out with this?

Comment: Please put the error messages you get from VLC and also include further details, such as, which DVD doesn't play (is it the original or ripped).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing libdvdread4 ?

If not do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Worked for me.

Comment: I have solved my problem. I installed win32codecs, an now it seems to work perfectly in VLC and AcidRip. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update

sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

try these..